# How to recover Sybase Username and Password?

Tags: sap-ase

I am getting the following error while connecting to Sybase with the credentials which I have. Unfortunately, the dba is not available who has set this up and there is no one who knows the password. Basically, I am looking to connect to Sybase `DB` on which `ECC` is installed from Power BI but not able to proceed due to this error. Sybase `DB` and `ECC` are installed on Linux Red Hat Enterprise.

```
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server '<SERVER_NAME>':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
       ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.
```

Comment: Assuming this is Sybase ASE ... you'll need to find someone with sso_role (eg, the DBA) who can reset your password; the same person could also verify your login exists and whether or not the account is locked.

Comment: Yes Mark, It is Sybase ASE. Unfortunately, there is no one in current team who has access to this system and the person who has installed it is not reachable. I understand our KT process should have been better. Any option other than someone with sso_role?

Comment: Resetting passwords (or unlocking accounts) is limited to someone with sso_role (typically also includes the DBA); there is no workaround for this otherwise you'd be looking at a major security hole; without any DBAs, and no one with sso_role permissions, (obviously?) your dataserver is at risk ... who's doing maintenance operations, who's creating/locking accounts, who's managing the dataserver, who/what is making backups, who would perform recovery operations, who's going to bring up the server if it goes down, who's going to add space/dbs ... ???

Comment: Agreed. I have the root OS credentials, Will that be of any help?

Comment: as root you should be able to su(do) to the owner of the ASE instance (in unix this is typically the 'sybase' user); you may have some luck hunting around the 'sybase' home directory (and sub-directories) ... see if the DBA left any passwords (eg, password for 'sa' account) in a file and if so, you could use that to login and reset your password; if you can't find the 'sa' password then the extreme situation would be to shutdown the dataserver (will probably require the UNIX/sybase account to kill the dataserver process) and then restart with the '-p sa' flag on the command line ...

Comment: ...  this will cause ASE to reset the 'sa' password and spit said password out to stdout, then use the new 'sa' password to log into ASE; if you go this route (killing the OS-level dataserver process) I'd recommend all users are out of the dataserver and you issue a normal 'kill' so as to give the dataserver a chance to shutdown cleanly (yes, you could do a 'kill -9' but there's no guarantee this will leave the dataserver in a usable state afterwards)

Comment: Just to close on this issue. EncryptPassword was set to Yes and so we were not able to connect from client. Now we are able to connect after passing EncryptPassword = Yes. Thanks a lot for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps

1:- shutdown the database

```
kill -9 <PID of the dataserver>
```

2:- Go to the install directory and add -psa clause to the dataserver RUN FILE:-

```
cd $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install
echo "-psa" >>RUN_File
```

3:- start the dataserver using startserver command:-

```
startserver -f  $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/RUN_File
```

4:- The output you can see the temporary password for “sa” user

```
New SSO password for sa:mhuybduaordzp6
```

5:- You can login to the ASE using this temporary password and then change the “sa” password using the sp_password procedure:-

```
sp_password "mhuybduaordzp6", "NewPassword", sa
go
```

Comment: kill -9 is not a good choice, kill on it's own is the equivalent of shutdown with no wait, which terminates client connections and closes the databases "cleanly". 

Kill -9 prevents the cleanly bit and recovery may take a while upon restart.

Comment: what is the better option when you are going to shutdown the database.

Comment: kill on its own or kill -15 which gives the dataserver process the opportunity to perform the equivalent of shutdown with no wait. Client connections will be terminated and transactions rolled back, caches flushed and "files" closed. With "kill -9" the Unix kernel never schedules the process and removes it.